# Can gender fraud be used to nullify a marriage in India?

Tags: united-states, india, divorce

### Hypothetical

- **A** is a male who married **B**, a woman, in India under Hindu religion.
- **A** had never met **B**, and relied on photographs and the efforts of third parties.
- The marriage is less than 2 months old.
- **A** is of the opinion that **B** has a masculine appearance and acts in a characteristically male manner.
- **A** currently lives in the U.S.
- **A** wants a divorce and anticipates that **B** will resist his efforts to divorce.

## Questions

- Can **A** successfully file for divorce or have the marriage annulled?
- What defenses can **B** assert to stop a divorce or annulment?

Comment: To prospective close-voters - consider whether the underlying and answerable question might be **is misrepresentation grounds for nullifying a marriage?**

Comment: @jimsug  please donot call this  misrepresentation, I am not trying to cheat anybody,I feel I am cheated. I need advice  on testing my suspicion on medical grounds

Comment: Errr. I'm trying to ask people to stop and think before **they** close your question. If you want to test your suspicion on medical grounds, this is not the right site for you. You might want to edit your question to ask whether, if a medical test did provide evidence that your wife is biologically male, you would have grounds to annul your marriage. Again, _I'm asking people to see past your question which is alarming at first so that it gets answered_.

Comment: @SurijahMann I don't think that's what jimsug meant. I think he meant misrepresentation *by your wife / through the pictures you received*.

Comment: Indeed I did - sorry, I should have made that clearer.

Comment: You say you are back in the States; which state?

Comment: To the downvoters - how about some feedback.

Comment: In the US, civil matters such as marriage, adoption, and divorce are legislated by the states.  States have different provisions in place for divorce, in particular.  It would therefore be useful to specify a state of residence for A.

Comment: A woman with a masculine appearance and acting in a "characteristically male manner" is not commiting "gender fraud".

Comment: @Yvide  I did some research   on this kind of male symptoms , I realized that it may be due to high levels of   testosterone , she might be having some medical condition, which I was never informed, she takes some pills, when asked she said it is for headache, google on the pill, found it has something to do with hormonal imbalance. I live in VA

Comment: @SurijahMann I recommend you go talk to a divorce lawyer. You may be able to get marriage annulled. But you need to act fast. Also maybe talk to a lawyer in the jurisdiction where you married.

Comment: "Masculine appearance" and "masculine voice" means that a huge, huge, huge piece of evidence is missing.

Comment: I've read up on India's laws and it seems that there are grounds for annulment in India if consent to marriage was given by fraud. I would strongly recommend you contact a divorce attorney in India. It also seems like the statue of limitations for seeking this type of annulment is 1 year.

Comment: @SurijahMann high levels of testosterone and/or treating a hormonal imbalance = still not committing fraud or posing as anything she isn't

Comment: "of the opinion that" and "fraud" are two vastly different things. The specifics of your request are unclear: is actual fraud (i.e. lying or deceiving about gender) proven, or is it just a hunch?

Answer (score 4):

First, it is quite unlikely that a US court would take on the case. Someone will have more details, but for example in EU law if you move away from the place you last lived together, you can only file for divorce in the country where your partner is living (in this case, India). Annullment is a much more serious matter than divorce, so I doubt any American court would take this case: Annulment would mean that a US court would have to decide that an Indian registry office didn't do its job right.

Second, **A** needs convincing evidence. Frankly, "masculine appearance" and "typical masculine voice" are just opinions and therefore not evidence. Even if the court were convinced that **B** has a "masculine appearance" that's not evidence for being a male. **A** has to show the evidence, and as half of us know and the other half learned in their biology lessons, there is some pretty convincing evidence that someone is a man which **A** didnt' mention. And I'd ask anyone not to edit this out, because it is quite essential to the case. **B** doesn't have to visit a doctor and get a statement that she is a woman (which would destroy any case immediately), because based on the available evidence, **A** will lose the case anyway.

On the other hand, after that court case has finished, **B** can at any time (after appropriate waiting times according to US law) come to the USA and file for divorce.

Comment: The original poster was up front. The question was edited to use **A** and **B** by someone else. The implication that the the original poster is somehow hiding something by using **A** and **B** rather than direct references, is a bit underserved.

Comment: That's a rubbish edit then.

Comment: Just use DNA tests

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question about gender:

In jurisdictions that do not allow same-sex marriages, a marriage is automatically considered invalid if it is discovered after the marriage that both partners are of the same sex.

- In the US and the UK, this is called a [void marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_marriage) (not to be confused with a *voidable* marriage, which is one that is not automatically void, but only if one partner requests it in court).
- In Germany, it would simliarly be a [Nichtehe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichtehe) (literally "non-marriage").
- In India, the [Hindu Marriage Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hindu_Marriage_Act,_1955) also defines a "void marriage" with similar rules. However, it does not explicitly mention same-sex marriages, so whether such a marriage is void would probably depend on interpretation by the court.

*Note:* Even if the marriage is not automatically void because of the same gender, it might still be void or voidable because of deception (if that can be proved). For example, in Germany a marriage is voidable (but not void) if one partner deceived the other to make them agree to the marriage.

That is a different question, however...